# Asymptotic notation basics

Tags: notation, asymptotics, computational-complexity

Say that we have the function $$ f(n)=kn, \, k>0 $$ does that imply the following? $$f(n) \in O(n), \, f(n) \in \Theta(n) \text{ and } f(n) \in \Omega(n)$$ I'm fairly new to these notations and am wondering if a function can be "in" all three at the same time.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. There's nothing preventing functions being in all three at the same time, and it's really easy to verify that your function indeed is.

Comment: Actually, more than "nothing prevents from": being $\Theta(n)$ **is equivalent to** being $O(n)$ and $\Omega(n)$ at the same time.